# How to iterate through a numbered list and every time value 1 appears start over?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dataframe

Given a list:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

While iterating though `list1`, every time the integer 1 is hit, start the loop over but increment it by 1.

Tried the two examples below but it only returns a list of 1's for the length of `list1`.

```py
digit = []
i = 0
for num in list1:
    num = i
    if num != 1:
        i += 1
        digit.append(i)
    elif num == 1:
        digit.append(num)
```

```py
digit = []
i = 0
for num in list1:
    num = i
    if num == 1:
        digit.append(num)
        continue
    elif num != 1:
        i += 1
        digit.append(i)  
digit
```

Looking to get something like the list below

```
digit = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

Comment: Can you explain how you got the output below?

Comment: There are 17 elements in `list1` but only 16 in `digit`.

Comment: Aren't you missing another 1 in the output?
[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]

Comment: The "for" statement sets "num" to a value from the list. The next line replaces that value with "i"

Comment: Yes, I missed a 1. Will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking this. Initialise a variable to zero. Append it to a list at each iteration. Increment if the corresponding list value is 1.

```
values = []
i = 0
for l in list1:
    if l == 1: # The check must come before appending. Can you explain why?
        i += 1

    values.append(i) 

values
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

---

If you were to ask me for a pythonic solution to this problem, I'd suggest [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import add 

list(accumulate((int(x == 1) for x in list1), add))
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Dude. How did you even understand what his problem statement was. I was scratching my head. ;-)

Comment: @SukumarRdjf identify/mark groups based on a certain value, a common pandas problem :)

Comment: That explains the 8k in pandas @cs95 :)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.  I definitely overthink everything. Had OrderedDicts nested under OrderedDicts that I could not flatten, so figured I would replicate the order and yes, it was for a Pandas DataFrame.